# PHP SOAP client namespacing

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I have a SoapClient instance and I'm trying to make a request (duh!). I am able to pass an array of parameters as key => value in the first level like, `securityToken`. But I can't send to the second namespace (I think that's what it is) `stap`. The following is a simplified version of what the inside of my ENV should look like. I know the Envelope should contain a reference to `xmlns:stap` but I can't work out how to get SoapClient to do that.

```
<soapenv:Body>
  <ns:PlaceOrder>
     <ns:securityToken></ns:securityToken>
     <ns:orderRequest>
        <stap:Headers>
           <stap:OrderRequestHeader>
              <stap:Lines>
                 <stap:OrderRequestLine>
                    <stap:QuantityRequested></stap:QuantityRequested>
                    <stap:StockCode></stap:StockCode>
                 </stap:OrderRequestLine>
              </stap:Lines>
           </stap:OrderRequestHeader>
        </stap:Headers>
     </ns:orderRequest>
  </ns:PlaceOrder>
```

And here's my _soap function

```
protected function _soap($request, $parameters = array(), $service = null, $options = array()) {
    $client     = new SoapClient($service, $options);
    $response   = $client->{$request}($parameters);
    return $response;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create PHP SOAP request with multiple namespaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998356/how-to-create-php-soap-request-with-multiple-namespaces)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998356/how-to-create-php-soap-request-with-multiple-namespaces..this is more useful for you

Comment: I've read that response a number of times and it seems rather opaque to me, and doesn't seem to give the request I want. What on earth is the auth object doing for example? I know I don't need one in a header. The answer doesn't tell me how to add a namespace.